# Compilation error with VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, compilation

I'm trying to compile [eViaCam](http://eviacam.sourceforge.net/) with Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2012. I've installed two libraries, OpenCV and wxWidgets. I had several problems, but I finally resolved them manually by adding several include paths (with, maybe, redundancy). But there is still a problem at the compilation :

```
1>  Génération de code en cours...
1>          1 fichier(s) copié(s). // Translation : "1 file copied."
1>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
1>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
1>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
1>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
1>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
1>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
1>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
1>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
1>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
1>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
1>          1 fichier(s) copié(s).
1>  Le fichier spécifié est introuvable. // Translation : "The specified file is not found"
1>  Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
1>  Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
1>  Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
1>  Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
1>  Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
1>  Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
1>  Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
1>  Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: La commande "mkdir C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\ca
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: mkdir C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\es
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: mkdir C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\gl
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: mkdir C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\it
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: mkdir C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\tr
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: mkdir C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\de
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: mkdir C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\oc
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: mkdir C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\fr
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: mkdir C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\ar
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: mkdir C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\he
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: mkdir C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\ru
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: mkdir C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\pt_BR
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: copy "C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\..\po\ca.gmo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\ca\eviacam.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: copy "C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\..\po\es.gmo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\es\eviacam.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: copy "C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\..\po\gl.gmo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\gl\eviacam.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: copy "C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\..\po\it.gmo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\it\eviacam.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: copy "C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\..\po\tr.gmo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\tr\eviacam.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: copy "C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\..\po\de.gmo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\de\eviacam.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: copy "C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\..\po\oc.gmo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\oc\eviacam.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: copy "C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\..\po\fr.gmo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\fr\eviacam.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: copy "C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\..\po\ar.gmo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\ar\eviacam.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: copy "C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\..\po\he.gmo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\he\eviacam.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: copy "C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\..\po\ru.gmo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\ru\eviacam.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: copy "C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\..\po\pt_BR.gmo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\pt_BR\eviacam.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: copy "%WXWIN%\locale\ca.mo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\ca\wxstd.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: copy "%WXWIN%\locale\es.mo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\es\wxstd.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: copy "%WXWIN%\locale\gl.mo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\gl\wxstd.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: copy "%WXWIN%\locale\it.mo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\it\wxstd.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: copy "%WXWIN%\locale\tr.mo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\tr\wxstd.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: copy "%WXWIN%\locale\de.mo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\de\wxstd.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: rem copy "%WXWIN%\locale\oc.mo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\oc\wxstd.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: copy "%WXWIN%\locale\fr.mo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\fr\wxstd.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: rem copy "%WXWIN%\locale\ar.mo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\ar\wxstd.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: rem copy "%WXWIN%\locale\he.mo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\he\wxstd.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: copy "%WXWIN%\locale\ru.mo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\ru\wxstd.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: copy "%WXWIN%\locale\pt_BR.mo" C:\eviacam-1.6.1\src\Release\bin\pt_BR\wxstd.mo
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(129,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" s'est arrêtée avec le code 1. // Translation : VCEnd has stopped with the code 1.
========== Génération : 0 a réussi, 1 a échoué, 0 mis à jour, 0 a été ignoré ==========
```

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is trying to create files on the C drive. In Windows 7 default account users dont normally have write permissions on the C drive.

You need to run the program in Administrator mode which is most recommended or set read-write permissions to the current user for the particular directory if you trust the program.

Please note that setting write permissions on C drive will invite serious issues and may also crash your system. So do it on your own risk -

On the parent folder containing all files you want to take full control of, do the following:

```
Right Click on the Folder 
Select Properties 
Navigate to Security tab 
Press the Advanced button 
Press the Change Permissions.. button 
Give your username full control 
Make sure Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object is selected 
Click Ok, Ok, and then Ok again to acknowledge.
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: This is not wokring.. i am running VS2012 as administrator but still seeing the issue.